# How to change the "while" loop to retrieve only 3 top records from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I set up the query to SELECT * FROM, 
Then I used the **while** loop to print out all retrieved records and it all works fine.
But what I need is to print out only the TOP 3 of those records, is there any way to change that **while** loop to make it work this way.

Any help on this will be much appreciated, thx

```
 while($row = $alerts_query->fetch_object()){

 echo "<div class='panel'>

   <div class='panel-heading'>
   <h3 class='panel-title'>" .  $row->ticket_title . " <a href='clientpanel.php?tab=dashboard=" .  $row->ticketId . "' aria-hidden='true' type='button' class='close pull-right'>x</a></h3>
   </div>
     <div class='panel-body'>" . $row->ticket_description . "
       <br />
       <br />
       <span style='color: #999'>Reported: " . $row->ticket_date . "</span>
     </div>
   </div>";

    }
```

Comment: Use `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not limit in the `while` loop (though, it's possible). Change your SQL instead:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
```

Append:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable LIMIT 3
```

If for some reason you **should** do it in PHP (not advised in this situation):

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $alerts_query->fetch_object() and $i<3) {
    $i++;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @user3277558 accept answers that helped solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`SELECT * FROM [table] LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 SELECT * FROM table LIMIT x ORDER BY ASC
```

where x in your case is 3

Answer (score 0):

It can achieved in many ways, using LIMIT clause is one of the approach. But following is according your scenario

```
 $i = 1;

while ($row = $alerts_query->fetch_object()) {

    if ($i > 3)
        break;
    echo "<div class='panel'>
           <div class='panel-heading'>
           <h3 class='panel-title'>" . $row->ticket_title . " <a href='clientpanel.php?tab=dashboard=" . $row->ticketId . "' aria-hidden='true' type='button' class='close pull-right'>x</a></h3>
           </div>
           <div class='panel-body'>" . $row->ticket_description . "
           <br />
           <br />
           <span style='color: #999'>Reported: " . $row->ticket_date . "</span>
               </div>
                </div>";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,3
```